# install certbot for nginx with react app and php subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, laravel, nginx, ssl, certbot

I have domain at 1 IP and subdomain at other IP. I had config nginx url for FE: http://subdomain/ and for BE: http://subdomain/api. And I need ssl for subdomain use **Certbot**, at this I have **react app for FE** and **php laravel for BE** all in **docker**, but not successfull.

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 8888;
    server_name subdomain;

    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www;
    client_max_body_size 256M;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/fe/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/fe/access.log;


    ## config path for API
    location ^~ /api  {
        error_log /var/log/nginx/api/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/api/access.log;

        alias /var/www/api/public;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^ /api/index.php last;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                return 404;
            }
            fastcgi_pass api:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
    }

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        default_type "text/plain" ;
        alias /var/www/certbot/index.html; <-- #here only static file html with "HelloWorld"
    }

    ## Load staic file for FE
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

And when I run verify **ssl for nginx** by **Certbot**:

```
certbot --nginx -d <subdomain> -m <email>
```

I have error as bellow:

```
   Domain: <subdomain>
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://<sudomain>/.well-known/acme-challenge/88C3jgQzqOTXDqBbDX_XLZRR0Sw5RGaNUaGyCgedwVs
   [IP]: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n
   <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n    <title>HelloWorld</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n\n</body>"
```

If I set block `/.well-known/acme-challenge` in nginx with only `allow all;` or `allow all; root /certbot/index.html;` I have error

```
   Domain: <subdomain>
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://<subdomain>/.well-known/acme-challenge/bfp9WEdPO1eb4NPTSPuQCD2jpakgn2-aIUVF62nrwLs
   [IP]: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not
   Found</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>404 Not
   Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.15.12</c"
```

How I can config nginx for ssl?

Thanks for support.

**UPDATED:**

Done I can fixed it. Because I set nginx and certbot in docker and run container without 443 port. Open map 443 and 80 port, it work like charm.

Comment: What does this have to do with Laravel or React ? This should be ask in [sf]

Comment: @matiaslauriti asked on Server Fault